# HTTPS traffic analysis

Tags: traffic, network-traffic, fingerprinting, network-flow, passive-mode

I'm working on a project where specifying the Operating System fingerprint of a client from the HTTPS request is a main requirement. Now for HTTP request it's easy to capture and read the header, but I'm asking what can I do to analyse the packets when it comes to the encrypted (HTTP secure) request?

And how much exactly can I know from HTTPS request header?

Comment: My guess is you decrypt it first and then you get the same old http with headers and everything.